# Groovy: Correct Syntax for XMLSlurper to find elements with a given attribute

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

Given a HTML file with the structure *html -> body -> a bunch of divs* what is the correct groovy statement to find all of the divs with a non blank tags attribute?

The following is not working:

```
def nodes = html.body.div.findAll { it.@tags != null }
```

because it finds all the nodes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following (Groovy 1.5.6):

```
def doc = """
<html>
    <body>
        <div tags="1">test1</div>
        <div>test2</div>
        <div tags="">test3</div>
        <div tags="4">test4</div>
    </body>
</html>
"""

def html = new XmlSlurper().parseText( doc)

html.body.div.findAll { it.@tags.text()}.each { div ->
    println div.text()
}
```

This outputs:

```
test1
test4
```