# Selecting using XmlSlurper like a WHERE clause

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

Given the following HTML snippet, I need to extract the text of the content attribute for the `meta` tag with attribute `name` equal to `description` and the `meta` tag with attribute `property` equal to `og:title`.  I've tried what is shown at [Groovy: Correct Syntax for XMLSlurper to find elements with a given attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100325/groovy-correct-syntax-for-xmlslurper-to-find-elements-with-a-given-attribute), but it doesn't seem to work the same in Groovy 1.8.6.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100003979125336" />
    <meta name="description" content="Shiny embossed blue butterfly" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Fancy That Blue Butterfly Platter" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Fancy That Blue Butterfly Platter" />
```

Is there a clean way to retrieve these with GPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with groovy 2.0.1 - I don't have 1.8.6 handy at the moment:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
File xmlFile = new File('sample.xml')
def xml = slurper.parseText(xmlFile.text)
println 'description = ' + xml.head.children().find{it.name() == 'meta' && it.@name == 'description'}.@content
println 'og:title = ' + xml.head.children().find{it.name() == 'meta' && it.@property == 'og:title'}.@content
```

Comment: Hmm, that gives me empty string in 1.8.6.  I've brute-forced it using indexOf, but I'd still like to understand why this doesn't work.